# Take every Nth element from an Observable

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I need to observe a stream that produces values at a regular interval, but there are too many values so I want to take, say one value for every ten values produced.

The equivalent, non-RX way to do that, would be:

```
int step = 10;  // take every 10th value
var numbers = Enumerable.Range(0, 100).Where((e, i) => i % step == 0);
```

What would be the idiomatic way to do that in Rx?

Comment: You can do the same: `Observable.Range(0, 100).Where((value, index) => index % step == 0)`

Comment: Consider using Throttle in Rx. http://www.introtorx.com/content/v1.0.10621.0/13_TimeShiftedSequences.html

Comment: @MistyK unfortunately Throttle wouldn't do, since my elements arrive at regular intervals, and according to docs _"the Throttle method is only useful for sequences that produce values at a variable rate. Sequences that produce values at a constant rate (like Interval or Timer) either would have all of their values suppressed if they produced values faster than the throttle period, or all of their values would be propagated if they produced values slower than the throttle period."_ This happens because Throttle is time-based, not index-based/count-based.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use either `Where` or `Buffer`:

```
int step = 10;  // take every 10th value

// Where
var numbers = Observable.Range(0, 100).Where((e, i) => i % step == 0);

// Buffer
numbers = Observable.Range(0, 100).Buffer(step).Select(x => x[step - 1]);
```

Comment: FYI: That is a working, but a quick&dirty solution. No problem if 'every' is 3 or 5, but it's 100, and if the items are heavy, it may add up to performance losses. If I read https://github.com/dotnet/reactive/blob/9a46e892bc761165664cb171f29724f5e55be827/AsyncRx.NET/System.Reactive.Async.Linq/System/Reactive/Linq/Operators/Buffer.cs properly, the Buffer() creates a new buffer for each cycle, so we've got a new array or list each time, plus all cached elements each time, just to pick the last and leave lots of trash for GC to clean up. TheodorZoulias's answer is much better!

Answer (score 3):

I would avoid using the `Where` operator taking the `Func<TSource, int, bool> predicate` parameter, out of fear of a possible `OverflowException`. This could happen in case the source sequence produces more than 2,147,483,647 elements. Both Linq and Rx operators allow arithmetic overflows to occur, and I am not aware of any workaround that prevents this from happening.

Here is a custom `TakeEvery` operator that is safe in that regard:

```
/// <summary>Samples the observable sequence by returning one every N elements,
/// ignoring the other elements.</summary>
public static IObservable<T> TakeEvery<T>(this IObservable<T> source, int step)
{
    if (step < 1) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(step));
    return Observable.Defer(() =>
    {
        int index = -1;
        return source.Where(value => (index = ++index % step) == 0);
    });
}
```